# Exponential distribution hypothesis testing

Tags: distributions, matlab, exponential-distribution

I want exponential distribution hypothesis testing with `MATLAB`. Is any test or method for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "how much fit"? What is this for?

Comment: I need exponential distribution hypothesis testing. I edited question. thanks

Comment: Huh. I understood (or at least thought to understood) the question as it was originally worded, but not really now...

Comment: You have dealt with neither part of my question but simply raised more questions. What do you mean by "how much fit", which is still in your question. What do you mean by "exponential distribution hypothesis testing" - testing what, in particular? If you're trying to see if data fits an exponential distribution with specified parameter, the second part of my initial question applies -- *WHY* would you do that? This is the most central question. If you're actually interested in knowing whether it's okay to use an exponential model for inference, formal testing of it may not be the best idea.

Comment: I have some databases that i want find which one of them is more fit to a specific exponential distribution. so i think hypothesis testing is the best solution for that. What do you think?

Comment: "If you're actually interested in knowing whether it's okay to use an exponential model for inference, formal testing of it may not be the best idea." Very good point indeed. My answer pertains to the case if you want to check _per se_ whether the data is coming from a prespecified distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use, for example, two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with [kstest2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html). (If the other distribution is also available as a sample. If it is a prespecified distribution (e.g. exponential with a priori known parameter) you can use [kstest](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html).)

I just noted from your comment that the sample size is very large, so you'll likely get a significant difference. (Which, however may not be important for you, as the test will have very high power, detecting even minuscule deviations.) Taking that into account, you might want to check a [QQ-plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) with

```
PD = ProbDistUnivParam('Exponential','mu',3)
qqplot(a,PD)
```

(following the example in the comment).

Comment: Can you add some codes for more helps? thanks.

Comment: @user2991243 : For which case? Do you have two data sets (i.e. two vectors with samples) or one sample and a prespecified distribution?

Comment: I have only one dataset. `700*1`

Comment: @user2991243 : OK. Lets say its in vector `a`. If you want to test whether it comes from an exponential distribution with parameter - say - $3$ you'll have to first run `test_cdf=makedist('Exponential','mu',3)` and then `kstest(a,'CDF',test_cdf)`. Just follow the links and examples in the page I cited...

Comment: @user2991243 : You're welcome! Be sure to read Nick Cox's answer, he raises very important points. (Why graphical methods are indeed preferred in many situations over hypothesis testing for this purpose.)

Comment: Yes. That's a good answer. I want select both answers as the best but i can't :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use the technology of the 1960s rather than the 1930s: Draw a quantile-quantile plot.

An exponential distribution has a simple quantile function. In practice, rank the data $y_{(1)} \le \dots \le y_{(n)}$ and calculate $-\ln[1 - (i - 0.5)/n]/\bar y$ for $i = 1(1)n$. The plot of the corresponding ordered series should be straight with slope $1$ and intercept $0$.

If a reference case is needed to judge whether small deviations from linearity are acceptable, then draw plots for several simulated samples of the same size from an exponential with the same mean and see if the plot for the real data can be identified in a line-up of suspects.

This has the signal advantage over almost any numerical significance test that if the fit is poor, you get to see where and why it is poor.

EDIT: Dennis's comment that the graphical analysis and a significance test can be complementary is diplomatic, even though it leaves open the question of what to do if they contradict each other.

A specific objection to Kolmogorov-Smirnov here is the suspicion that it works rather better at telling distributions apart that differ in their middles, which for an exponential is arguably the wrong way round. More on that in Miller, R.G. 1986. *Beyond ANOVA.* New York: John Wiley, p.14

At a deeper level, a quantile-quantile plot from a single dataset **is** a sample statistic; it is the result of manipulations of a sample; only hidebound tradition insists that "sample statistic" means a numeric scalar serving as summary. Similarly a sampling distribution of quantile-quantile plots from simulations can serve as reference distribution. The idea has attracted much attention over the last few years, but was already explicit in Shewhart, W.A. 1931. *Economic control of quality of manufactured product.* New York: Van Nostrand. (Shewhart's title downplays the general statistical content of his monograph.)

Comment: Or, you can do both of the above.  The Q-Q plot tells you where and how substantial the deviations from the model are.  The K-S test (which is based on the supremum of $\hat{F} - F$) tells you whether that difference can be reasonably attributed to sampling error.